# Improve SQL query for filtering results by values stored in "external" tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

To make things easier, let's say that I have a table representing pretty simple user's feed.

There are two "key" columns in my `feed` table:

`object_id` it's a ID of different assets, e.g. comment, post, etc.

`entity_type_id` it's a basically reference to another table in my DB.

The "children" tables may have some attributes in common, e.g. `is_hidden`, `is_deleted` and `is_locked` (however, they are not replicated across all tables).

Now, I'd like to implement a filter that should filter out my feed items, based on the values of these three attributes.

What I did so far?

```
SELECT `f`.* 
FROM `feed` `f`
WHERE 1
-- !!! Other filters goes here. ---
AND 
(
    --
    -- !!! Filter by status
    --
    (   -- "Locked" (not all children tables have this column)
        (
            `f`.`entity_type_id` = 1 AND `f`.`object_id` IN ( SELECT `fb_comment_id` FROM `comments` WHERE `is_locked` = 1  AND `fb_page_id` IN('0123456789') )
        )
        OR
        (
            `f`.`entity_type_id` = 4 AND `f`.`object_id` IN ( SELECT `fb_post_id` FROM `posts` WHERE `is_locked` = 1 AND `fb_page_id` IN('0123456789') )
        )
    ) 
    (   -- "Hidden" (not all children tables have this column)
        (
            `f`.`entity_type_id` = 1 AND `f`.`object_id` IN ( SELECT `fb_comment_id` FROM `comments` WHERE `is_hidden` = 1  AND `fb_page_id` IN('0123456789') )
        )
        OR
        (
            `f`.`entity_type_id` = 4 AND `f`.`object_id` IN ( SELECT `fb_post_id` FROM `posts` WHERE `is_hidden` = 1 AND `fb_page_id` IN('0123456789') )
        )
    ) 
    OR 
    (
        -- "Deleted"
        (
            `f`.`entity_type_id` = 1 AND `f`.`object_id` IN ( SELECT `fb_comment_id` FROM `comments` WHERE `is_deleted` = 1 AND `fb_page_id` IN ('0123456789') )
        ) 
        OR
        (
            `f`.`entity_type_id` = 3 AND `f`.`object_id` IN ( SELECT `insta_comment_id` FROM `instagram_comments` WHERE `is_deleted` = 1 AND `insta_profile_id` IN ('9876543210') )
        )
        OR 
        (
            `f`.`entity_type_id` = 4 AND `f`.`object_id` IN ( SELECT `fb_post_id` FROM `posts` WHERE `is_deleted` = 1 AND `fb_page_id` IN ('0123456789') )
        )
        OR 
        (
            `f`.`entity_type_id` = 5 AND `f`.`object_id` IN ( SELECT `insta_post_id` FROM `instagram_posts` WHERE `is_deleted` = 1 AND `insta_profile_id` IN ('9876543210') )
        )
    )
)
```

As you can see I was using sub queries, but I was wondering is there a better way to write such queries?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's better, but I'd create a subquery that unions the necessary flag fields from your child tables and then just do a regular join to get the flag fields. If a flag field is not present for one of the tables, it can just be false.

Something like:

```
SELECT `f`.* 
FROM `feed` `f`
JOIN
    (
        SELECT  
            1 AS `entity_type_id`
        ,   fb_comment_id AS `object_id`
        ,   is_locked
        ,   is_hidden
        ,   is_deleted
        FROM
            comments

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  
            4 AS `entity_type_id`
        ,   fb_post_id AS `object_id`
        ,   is_locked
        ,   is_hidden
        ,   is_deleted
        FROM
            posts

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  
            3 AS `entity_type_id`
        ,   insta_comment_id AS `object_id`
        ,   0 AS is_locked
        ,   0 AS is_hidden
        ,   is_deleted
        FROM
            instagram_comments

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  
            5 AS `entity_type_id`
        ,   insta_post_id AS `object_id`
        ,   0 AS is_locked
        ,   0 AS is_hidden
        ,   is_deleted
        FROM
            instagram_posts
    ) AS flag_summary ON (
        flag_summary.entity_type_id = f.entity_type_id
    AND flag_summary.object_id = f.object_id
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

1. Try to use INNER JOIN instead of WHERE + correlated queries. Create for example a table with all the tables in the sub-queries, and apply your filters. Do not forget to use `PROCEDURE ANALYSE` and index.
2. Avoid `SELECT *`, type all the variables you need.
3. Apply an `EXPLAIN` to know where you can improve your script.